# Direct calculation of the Fourier transform of a complex exponential

Tags: fourier-transform

I have found it hard to find an intuitive proof for the Fourier transform of a complex exponential, $f(t) = e^{i\omega_0t} $, via direct calculation. The vast majority of pages online use the inverse FT of $ 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)$. Looking online, I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_distribution) definition of the delta function, and have attempted to use it in a derivation. I would like to know if the following would be acceptable in a standard engineering signals course:
$$\begin{align*}
 F(\omega) &= \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{-T}^{T}e^{i\omega_0t}e^{-i{\omega}t} dt \\
&= \lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{-T}^{T}e^{-it(\omega-\omega_0)} dt \\
&= \lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{e^{iT(\omega-\omega_0)}-e^{-iT(\omega-\omega_0)}}{i(\omega-\omega_0)}\\
&=\lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{2{\sin}[T(\omega-\omega_0)]}{\omega-\omega_0}
\end{align*}$$

Now, we can perform a change of variables $\tau = \frac{\pi}{T}$, causing our limit to now approach zero (From here on is what I am unsure of):
$$\begin{align*}
F(\omega) &=\lim_{\tau\to0} \frac{2\sin[\frac{\pi(\omega-\omega_0)}{\tau}]}{\omega-\omega_0} \\
&= 2\pi \lim_{\tau\to0}\frac{\sin[\frac{\pi(\omega-\omega_0)}{\tau}]}{\pi(\omega-\omega_0)} \\
\end{align*}$$

According to the Wikipedia article linked above:
$$
\lim_{\tau\to0}\frac{\sin[\frac{\pi(\omega-\omega_0)}{\tau}]}{\pi(\omega-\omega_0)} = \delta(\omega-\omega_0)
$$

And therefore we can conclude:

$$
F(\omega) = 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_0)
$$

Overall, what do people think about this derivation?

Comment: The limit you use is more a property of the Dirac delta than its definition. The limit seems correct but you should know what you are doing, this is a limit in the sense of distributions.